# Stuck with the userInput in my hangman game (Java)

Tags: java

I would like to create a hangman game that could be played by 2 players. Player 1 gives the word that the other player needs to guess. Player 2 got unlimited attemps.

My problem is that I need to give the whole word instead of letters. I would like to have a function in my game where player 2 can quess the word with an input of letters. I know that I need to use a StringBuffer for letting this work, but I don't know how I need to do this.

I'm new to Java and I always like to learn!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Hangman {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hangman");
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(50,50,800,600);


        //OBJECTS
        JButton start = new JButton("START");
        start.setBounds(140,80,110,30);
        frame.getContentPane().add(start);
        frame.repaint();

        JButton guess = new JButton("GUESS");
        guess.setBounds(280,80,110,30);
        frame.getContentPane().add(guess);
        frame.repaint();


        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String tip = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Give a tip for the user.");

                JLabel givenTip = new JLabel(tip);
                givenTip.setBounds(50, 300, 300, 40);
                frame.getContentPane().add(givenTip);
                frame.repaint();

                JButton buttons = new JButton();

                String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the word?");

                for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {

                    buttons = new JButton("___");
                    buttons.setBounds(50 + (i * 80), 350, 60, 40);

                    frame.getContentPane().add(buttons);
                    frame.repaint();
                }

                guess.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                //I think that I need to add this function here.
                String inputUser = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Give a letter.");

                if (word.equals(inputUser)) {


                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"This is right!");

                        JLabel won = new JLabel("You won the game!");
                        won.setBounds(50, 400, 110, 40);
                        frame.getContentPane().add(won);


                        JLabel restart = new JLabel("Restart the game to play again.");
                        restart.setBounds(50, 500, 250, 40);
                        frame.getContentPane().add(restart);


                        JButton correctInput = new JButton(inputUser);
                        correctInput.setBounds(210, 400, 300, 40);
                        frame.getContentPane().add(correctInput);
                        frame.repaint();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"This is not right.");


                    }



            }

        });





            }
        });

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: There are _a lot_ of hangman questions here. Just search for them and you'll find what you need.

Answer (score 0):

with `if (word.equals(inputUser)) {` you are just checking if the input is the complete word not just a letter.

```
char[] charArray = inputUser.toCharArray();
if (charArray.length == 1) {
   //checks if the input is only one character
   //now you can check if the word contains this letter
   // and find the buttons with '__' and replace them with the letter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could firstly keep a version of player1's word, but made up of underscores ( _ ), so it's easier to add letters on right positions when guessed and also better to visualise by player2.

You could then add a button for player2 to make a **Guess** and in the listener method for that button just do (via a method call) the usual checks like so:

1) is guessed letter part of player1's word? if so add it on the right position in player2's word (find positions in player1's word)

2) is player1's word the same as player2's? Then inform player2 that he has won

3) if you decide to implement defeat as well (E.g. after a number of guesses have been made), also add a check here for this too. If you need any other game-logic functionality, you could add it here as well.